# VLC Media Player Audio Output to Android via Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth-audio, vlc

How can I output just the audio of a file playing on my VLC Media Player on my laptop via bluetooth, no cords? Is there a software or setting that I need to apply? I don't want to use the usb cable and just want the audio on my phone not the video.

Using Windows 8.1 with VLC 2.1.5, Broadcom 2070 and KitKat on Note 3 so I have Bluetooth v4.0, A2DP, EDR, LE.

Thanks to all.